# Is it possible to insert NSObjectController to responder chain?

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode-storyboard, first-responder, nsmenuitem

I've created an instance of NSObjectController (MenuObject on the image below) and method(test5:) for item's action there.

NSMenuItem is gray when I create a connection to First responder.
And it works fine when I create a IBAction directly.

I think it's because my NSObjectController(MenuObject) doesn't part of responder chain. No one can responds to selector and that's why item is grey. But how to fix it?

Thanks.

[image: NSMenuItem's action connected to First Responder]

Comment: You can add subclasses of NSResponder to the responder chain. Why do you use NSObjectController?

Comment: I don't want to use AppDelegate for menuItems` actions. It seems like good idea to store it together in a separate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSObjectController` is a data-flow controller. Putting it in the responder chain does not make real sense.

However, you should read about the [responder-chain for action messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW9). Doing so, you will prefer to put the action method into a window controller.